# Java Restful service encoding with special chars

Tags: java, xml, rest, encoding

im having problem whith a POST request. I have to receive an XML message and im parsing it with JAXB. Everithing works fine but when special chars are included in the message like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sending>
    <sms>
        <message>España</message>
    </sms>
</sending>
```

it throws a Bad Request Error (400)
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad Request).

This is my code to process the xml message

```
@POST
@Path("smsSendPost")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response smsSendPost(JAXBElement<Sending> xml){
    Sending sending = xml.getValue();

    //Process the message
}
```

Im using tomcat to test it.

Can anyone help me with this?

UPDATE:
I've just found the cause of the problem is the tomcat, when I send the request via POST with  ISO-8859-1 encoding the service works fine. The solution is to change the encoding of the tomcat.

Comment: At first glance I'd say an issue of encoding. Which did you use? Unicode? Have you tried adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Yes, i've tried that but still throws the error

Comment: how are you creating the xml request?

Comment: In the xml `<sending>` is small but `Sending` class is with capital "S" ? Just a wild guess ... By the way, does this very request succeed _without_ special chars?

Comment: what does Sending.java looks like ? how are you submitting your request? via some testing tool? browser extension? code ? it could be anything really

Comment: im using a rest client tool [Rest Client](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found that the cause of the problem is the tomcat, when I send the request via POST with ISO-8859-1 encoding the service works fine. I guess the solution is to change the encoding of the tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

The content type could be the issue but that depends on what content type you generate in the POST on the client and what character set is being used by the XML parser on the receiving end.

One alternative which is feasible in many situations like this is to use CDATA (unparsed character data) blocks in your XML where special characters can occur.

```
<sending>
    <sms>
        <message><![CDATA[España]]></message>
    </sms>
</sending>
```

By default an XML parser will attempt to parse all of the text in an XML message.  CDATA blocks tell a XML parser not to parse the characters contained within the CDATA block.

If your service that is receiving this cannot identify the character, it may be erroring out or assuming the XML is not well formed and throwing the 400 you are seeing.

More on CDATA blocks : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Can you add your entire POST request?  It's possible that the test tool you are using is converting the XML in some way which is making your service think it is no longer valid XML, causing the service to throw the 400.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your client is sending an invalid request. I suspect that you're using some non-UTF8 encoding and doesn't specify its name in [`Content-Type` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). If you post full HTTP request I may be able to diagnose the problem with more details.

Comment: Content-Encoding has nothing to do with charset. Charset might be specified as part of the Content-Type header.

Answer (score 0):

Thing that sticks out to me is you're not specifying a [@Consumes](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) annotation... Try adding `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` on your method. Also make sure to send `Content-Type` and have the appropriate `<?xml` tag specifying character encoding.